# Are the directrix line and focus unique for a conic?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

> How to prove of disprove the **uniqueness** of pair of (or single for parabola) **directrix** line and pair of **focal points** for a conics?

(Ignore the degenerate cases and the circle.)

Comment: How are you defining a conic? What would you say about the directrix of a circle?

Comment: All the definition of conics are equivalent so that does not matter how we are defining conic. To prove a statement we take the definition from which the proof is most trivial.

Comment: @MarkBennet if you still insist in the definition of conic you may take it as, the locus of point such that the ratio of distance between the point and focus to the distance of point from the directrix line is constant.

Comment: And please ignore the degenerate cases and the case for the circle.

Comment: The reason it matters is that when you want to prove something you have to know what you can assume. Assuming that various definitions are equivalent is a very strong assumption in the first place. Also there are various degenerate forms of conic and special cases which may be included/excluded. Is a circle a conic under the definition you have suggested? [It would also make a difference if you were working in the projective plane]

Comment: In the above definition of conics circle is of course a conic with eccentricity =0, but in the comment I have stated that to ignore circle and degenerate cases.

Comment: Moreover I would be grateful if the question is answered from the algebraic point of view that is through analytic geometry, as I am not quite accustomed with projective geometry.

Comment: If you are looking for an algebraic approach, you should know that depending on your definition, a conic will have four foci over the complex numbers. For a real conic, they form two pairs, one real and one with non-zero imaginary coordinates. Each comes with its own directrix, which is its polar line. So if you want to show that there are only two, you will at some point need to argue that some things under some square root will have to become negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose a generic parabola $y=ax^2$ (with $a>0$), defined as the locus of points having the same distance from a given focus $F=(0,1/(4a))$ and a given directrix $d$ of equation $y=-1/(4a)$ (the argument for an ellipse or hyperbola is similar but is left to the reader). We must prove that no other pair point/line can be a focus/directrix for the parabola.

Let $F'$, $d'$ be a possible focus/directrix pair. We show at first that $d'$ is parallel to $d$. For if it were not so, we could consider two points $P$, $Q$ on the parabola such that $PQ\parallel d'$, so that $P$ and $Q$ have the same distance from $d'$. That would imply $PF'=QF'$, hence $F'$ would lie on the perpendicular bisector of $PQ$. But a different line $P'Q'\parallel d'$ has a different perpendicular bisector, as you can easily show, parallel to the previous one, which is impossible because $F'$ cannot lie on two different parallel lines. (The case when $d'$ is parallel to the $y$-axis must be treated separately, but it's easily dealt with, as in that case $d'$ would intersect the parabola).

Hence $d'$ must be parallel to $d$. Suppose then $y=-k$ is the equation of $d'$, which entails $F'=(0,k)$. We must have $k>0$, for otherwise $d'$ would intersect the parabola and that leads to a contradiction. Consider then point $S=(\sqrt{k/a},k)$ on the parabola. Its distance from $F'$ is $\sqrt{k/a}$, while its distance from $d'$ is $2k$. Hence it must be $\sqrt{k/a}=2k$, that is $k/a=4k^2$ and $k=1/(4a)$: that proves that $F'=F$ and $d'=d$.

Comment: Your answer appears to only cover the case of a parabola. While I can see that as a valuable contribution, it is not a complete answer, so I suggest you say so up front.

Comment: @MvG I wrote "the argument for an ellipse or hyperbola is similar", I'll add that I  leave it to the reader.